# How can I create a non-plugin LLVM pass?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I have built LLVM/Clang under Linux, and followed the instructions at http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html to create an LLVM shared object pass plugin. The plugin can then be loaded using LLVM's `opt` program and the `-load` switch. Based on the LLVMHello and LLVMHello2 examples, I have now created a pass of my own.

Is a plugin the only method I can use to incorporate a pass into LLVM/Clang? I would like to build my pass directly in to the LLVM/Clang source, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

Just link your pass to opt and it will be available there. All standard passes are in lib/Transforms/*, so you can use them as examples.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can just copy your source into lib/Transforms/ and adjust build system files.
Here is info on how to do it with CMake: http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#passdev